# C# ASP.NET MVC : I'm trying to write a test to see if registering a new user succeeds

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, integration-testing, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET MVC app with a basic `Register` page. This is the specific function that register's new users.

Register.cshtml.cs:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
        var returnUrl = Url.Content("~/Home/PostRegister");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");

                var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = user.Id, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);

                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
}
```

This is the test that I wrote for it in my integration test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task DoesRegisterSucceed()
{
        // Arrange
        var client = _factory.CreateClient(
            new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            });
        
        var postRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/Identity/Account/Register");
        var formModel = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Email", "test@example.com" },
            { "Password", "pas3w0!rRd" },
            { "ConfirmPassword", "pas3w0!rRd" },
        };

        postRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formModel);
        var response = await client.SendAsync(postRequest);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        //var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
}
```

I get this error when I run the test.

> Failed amaranth.Tests.AuthTests.Get_ClaimAdminIsReturnedForFirstRegistered [505 ms]
> Error Message:
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
> at amaranth.Tests.AuthTests.Get_ClaimAdminIsReturnedForFirstRegistered() in /path/to/dir/amaranth.Tests/IntegrationTests/AuthTests.cs:line 102
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---

How can I make this test or write a new test that ensures registration succeeds?

**Update**
In case it's relevant this is my `CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs` file that's I'm using:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using amaranth.Data;

namespace amaranth.Tests
{
    #region snippet1
    public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
        : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup: class
    {
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                    d => d.ServiceType ==
                        typeof(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>));

                services.Remove(descriptor);

                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
                });

                var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

                using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
                {
                    var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                    var db = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                    var logger = scopedServices
                        .GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                    db.Database.EnsureCreated();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Did you figure out why success code is not returned in the test? Were you able to debug the test to understand what is happening during the test run?

Comment: No, still stuck on this. Do you know how to test registration success?

Comment: The HttpStatusCode of 400 is your clue.  Run the integration test in "debug test" mode.  Step through each line of the test and the OnPostAsync() methods.  Make sure the OnPostAsync() successfully creates an account.  Inspect what's in the response variable after it comes back from the controller call.

Comment: put a breakpoint on all returns to check which is triggering during test, you'll know why you're getting a 400

Comment: Are these tests in a separate project? I mean do you first run the server then you run these tests?

Comment: This is the best I could do debugging wise. Everything is running perfect until the response which is a 400 https://imgur.com/a/MAZIXWw. Is there any way to simply test Register and inject the model into the test?

Comment: @AMunim I also added my `CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs` file to the main thread in case it's relevant.

Comment: This is a breakpoint on response. Go into your controller, attach a breakpoint on `return Page()` and `return LocalRedirect()`. Then test in debug mode

Comment: @AMunim That's weird. The code never touched my breakpoints... Btw I have the code in 2 seperate parallel directories. They're both under the same sln file though. It looks like this `parentdir/amaranth/amaranth.csproj` and `parentdir/amaranth.Tests/amaranth.Tests.csproj`

Comment: I see you have copied this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0. Can you try removing InMemoryDb and using a real one just to check if startup class registers everything correctly.

Comment: @AMunim I deleted `options.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");` but they all failed with "No database provider" Error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245161/discussion-between-nextnightflyer-and-amunim).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is failing because you don't include an antiforgery cookie and verification token in the POST, hence the 400 status code. From [this page in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests):

> Any POST request to the SUT must satisfy the antiforgery check that's
> automatically made by the app's data protection antiforgery system. In
> order to arrange for a test's POST request, the test app must:
>
> 1. Make a request for the page.
> 2. Parse the antiforgery cookie and request validation token from the response.
> 3. Make the POST request with the antiforgery cookie and request validation token in place.